# Get JSON Results with POST Request with Parameters

Tags: json, swift, http-post, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest

How can I use a POST request with parameters to get JSON? I know how to do it with a simple GET request. The request url is http://gyminyapp.azurewebsites.net/api/Gym and the parameter query is

```
{
  "SearchCircle": {
    "Center": {
      "Latitude": 0,
      "Longitude": 0
    },
    "Radius": 0
  },
  "City": "string",
  "ZipCode": 0,
  "Type": "string"
}
```

I'm wanting to just use the search circle portion of this, which means I can ignore the City and ZipCode fields. I need to provide Latitude/Longitude, which I getting from the current user location. I also need to set the Type to "radius".

For a simple GET request using the GET version of this, I do this.

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://gyminyapp.azurewebsites.net/api/Gym")
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
            for gym in json as! [AnyObject] {
                gyms.append(gym)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }
```

Comment: If it works with a GET, why do you want to use a POST? Moreover, if you're retrieving data, GET is the more appropriate verb for it.

Comment: In my API, the GET gives me all of locations in my database. This POST lets me narrow the results down with certain criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a working code, you just need to put the values of your request parameters.

```
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let url = "http://gyminyapp.azurewebsites.net/api/Gym"
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let params:[String: AnyObject] = ["Type" : "string","SearchCircle" : ["Radius" : 0, "Center" : ["Latitude" : 0, "Longitude" : 0]]]
    do{
        request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            if let response = response {
                let nsHTTPResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
                let statusCode = nsHTTPResponse.statusCode
                print ("status code = \(statusCode)")
            }
            if let error = error {
                print ("\(error)")
            }
            if let data = data {
                do{
                let jsonResponse = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions())
                print ("data = \(jsonResponse)")
                }catch _ {
                    print ("OOps not good JSON formatted response")
                }
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }catch _ {
        print ("Oops something happened buddy")
    }
```

Then in the `if let data = data` you'd need to parse the response. I checked the response, it is JSON formatted array.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it. Just make an `NSDictionary` out of params and convert to `NSData`, I called that postData. And then the usual, send that postData as `requestBody`

```
        let parameters = [
            "SearchCircle": 
               [ "Center" : 
                  ["Latitude" : 0, 
                   "Longitude" : 0] ]
            "Radius" : 0, 
            "City" : "", ...
            ... and so on


            ]            ]
        do
        {
            let postData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: .PrettyPrinted)

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http...")!,
                                              cachePolicy: .UseProtocolCachePolicy,
                                              timeoutInterval: 10.0)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

            request.HTTPBody = postData

            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                if (error != nil) {
                    print(error)
                } else {
                    let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse
                    print(httpResponse)
                    do {
                        // JSON serialization
                        self.dictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as! NSDictionary
                        // if any data
                    }
                    catch {

                    }
                }
            })

            dataTask.resume()
        }
        catch {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the accepted answer's code updated for Swift 4:

```
    let url = "http://gyminyapp.azurewebsites.net/api/Gym"
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: url))

    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let params:[String: AnyObject] = ["Type" : "string",
                                      "SearchCircle" : ["Radius" : 0, "Center" : ["Latitude" : 0, "Longitude" : 0]]]
    do{
      request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions())
      let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
          let nsHTTPResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
          let statusCode = nsHTTPResponse.statusCode
          print ("status code = \(statusCode)")
        }
        if let error = error {
          print ("\(error)")
        }
        if let data = data {
          do{
            let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions())
            print ("data = \(jsonResponse)")
          }catch _ {
            print ("OOps not good JSON formatted response")
          }
        }
      })
      task.resume()
    }catch _ {
      print ("Oops something happened buddy")
    }
  }
```